# How to convert float list to string list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list which contains these float numbers: 35.1, 35.2, 35.10,...

The problem that when I convert this list of float numbers to get another list of strings, 35.10 will be 35.1.

This is my example:

```
a = [35.1,35.2,35.3,35.10,35.2,35.3]
str_a = [format(flt) for flt in a] 
print str_a
['35.1', '35.2', '35.3','35.1', '35.2', '35.3']
```

How can I rectify this problem? In my work the two numbers 35.1 and 35.10 are different

Comment: and how *35.1 and 35.10* are different?

Comment: When you create `a`, `35.10` will be converted to `35.1` straight away. So you will have to use strings when creating `a`

Comment: If these are representing floating point numbers, then 35.10 is the same as 35.1 is the same as 35.100000. If they are representing something else (like major.minor versions or book chapter.verse) then you may have a case where you want 35.1, 35.2, ... 35.9, 35.10, 35.11 to be sorted in that order.

Comment: to be fair they'll likely be converted to 35.0999999...5 or 35.1000000000.....5

Comment: Thank you for your response, these float numbers represent the IDs of my packets in my network so 35.1 and 35.10 are different packets generated by the Node 35. So my list a = [35.1,35.2,35.3,35.10,35.2,35.3]  all packets received by different destinations, so I need to know how the total number of packets received, normally the result from the list a gives 4 because the packets 35.2 and 35.3 are received two times so I don't count them.  My principal problem the result gives 3 because it considers 35.10 is the same packet 35.1. There is a solution please to resolve this issue?

Comment: If they are id numbers, don't create floats. Treat them as strings all the way.

Comment: The problem is that Python considers them as floats. I tried to change for example the id 35.10 to 35Z10, I replaced the point as chacarter to consider it as string but I got also an error. So do you know a solution enabling python to consider them as string please?

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible given the original question. A floating-point number does not have a fixed number of decimals (thus the name "floating point"!). You need to do this earlier, before you create your list of floats.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible to distinguish between 35.1 and 35.10

```
>>> 35.1 == 35.10
True
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, these float numbers represent the IDs of my packets in my network so 35.1 and 35.10 are different packets generated by the Node 35. So my list a = [35.1,35.2,35.3,35.10,35.2,35.3] all packets received by different destinations, so I need to know how the total number of packets received, normally the result from the list a gives 4 because the packets 35.2 and 35.3 are received two times so I don't count them. My principal problem the result gives 3 because it considers 35.10 is the same packet 35.1. There is a solution please to resolve this issue?

Answer (score -2):

perhaps you can try:

```
a = [35.1,35.2,35.3,35.10,35.2,35.3]
map(lambda x: '%.2f' % x, a)
```

which gives you:

```
['35.10', '35.20', '35.30', '35.10', '35.20', '35.30']
```

Comment: @Mitch `35.1 -> '35.10'`

Comment: @Mitch OP still has the same problem with not being able to distinguish between `35.1` and `35.10`

Comment: OH hah I didn't see that they are seriously viewing those as different numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your response, these float numbers represent the IDs of my packets in my network so 35.1 and 35.10 are different packets generated by the Node 35. So my list a = [35.1,35.2,35.3,35.10,35.2,35.3] all packets received by different destinations, so I need to know how the total number of packets received, normally the result from the list a gives 4 because the packets 35.2 and 35.3 are received two times so I don't count them. My principal problem the result gives 3 because it considers 35.10 is the same packet 35.1. There is a solution please to resolve this issue?